# Constructor of struct with fields dependent on feature

Tags: rust, struct

I have a struct that changes depending on a feature how should I handle constructor to make my code the most maintainable.

```
struct test {
    always_field: i32,
    #[cfg(feature = "feature")]
    feature_field: i32,
}

impl test {
    fn new() -> Self {
         Self {
             always_field: 12313,
             #[cfg(feature = "feature")]
             feature_field: 129090,
         }
    }
}
```

This works but looks awful I want to know if there is a better way to do this. I thought about creating a full "new" function but if I have multiple features that change the struct this gets out of hand real quick.

One thing I thought was to at least have `#[cfg]` be able to cover an arbitrary number of lines not only the next statement, but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: without know the overall design of the project and the purpose is hard to propose better.

Comment: Just a note: ensure the fields are private or the struct is marked `#[non_exhaustive]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to consider is, instead of changing the field's existence, change its type.

```rust
struct Test {
    always_field: i32,
    feature_field: second_field::SecondField,
}

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Self {
         Self {
             always_field: 12313,
             feature_field: SecondField::default(),
         }
    }
}

use second_field::SecondField;

#[cfg(feature = "feature")]
mod second_field {
    pub(super) struct SecondField(i32);
    
    impl Default for SecondField {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self(129090)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "feature"))]
mod second_field {
    #[derive(Default)]
    pub(super) struct SecondField();
}
```

In other use cases (not needing a unique initial value) you might simply change a `type SecondField =` type alias rather than defining an entirely new type and a module to contain it.

The advantage of this approach is that all the places you *use* the type don't need to mention the `cfg` at all — as long as the two different types are usable in the same ways.

However, in other cases it will be just worse boilerplate than the `cfg` you already have. It depends on how often the field is used.